# Tailwind: both external monitor and laptop screen are considered to be xl but big difference in size: make navbar behave differently

Tags: css, responsive-design, screen-size, tailwind-css

I have a laptop with 15.6'' screen and an external monitor with 23'' screen. I have a `.vue` component with this code:

```
<template>
  <div class="bg-red-500 sm:bg-green-500 md:bg-blue-500 lg:bg-pink-500 xl:bg-teal-500">
    Hello
  </div>
</template>
```

It shows this when I view it on laptop screen:

[image]

- the `teal` color which corresponds to the `xl` screen size.

The `div` has the same `teal` color when I move it to the external monitor.

However the difference between the screen sizes is significant. If both the 15.5'' and 23'' are considered to be `xl`, how does one achieves better responsiveness?

For instance, I have a navbar with several navbar items. When I view it on the laptop screen, I need to make the padding `px-2` small to get them all to fit:

[image]

However on the 23'' screen I have space to add more padding/margin, but can't do it because the changes would affect the laptop view as well:
[image]

This is the code of the `NavbarItem.vue`:

```
<template>
    <li class="flex-1 md:flex-none md:mr-3
                    sm:text-xs md:text-xs lg:text-xs xl:text-xs
                    border rounded-full">
        <a class="inline-block py-2 lg:px-5 xl:px-2
                    text-white no-underline" href="#">
            {{text}}
        </a>


    </li>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['text']
    }
</script>
```

I tried adding `lg:px-5` but it doesn't affect anything, unless I remove `xl:px-2`. When there's `xl:px-2`, the `lg` class is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

**xl** has a min-width of **1280px**. Check [breakpoints](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints).

Your 15.6" and 23" both screens falls under minimum of 1280px. I recommend adding additional screen.

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'xxl': {'min': '1920px'}, // this is to support your 23". Make sure your 15.6" screen is less than the min px value passed here
    },
  }
}
```

Then your `class="inline-block py-2 lg:px-5 xl:px-2 xxl:px-4"`

Give this a try & keep me posted in the comments below. Cheers!